# SQL Server : Getting the query raising an error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm using the `usp_RethrowError` ( given as example in [Using TRY...CATCH in Transact-SQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296.aspx) article on [technet.microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com) site ) when signaling something is wrong.

Is there any way to get the query which triggers this error inside the `usp_RethrowError` procedure ? I would also like to add the query text to the `@ErrorMessage`.

You can find below the code for usp_RethrowError stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_RethrowError AS
    -- Return if there is no error information to retrieve.
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() IS NULL
        RETURN;

    DECLARE 
        @ErrorMessage    NVARCHAR(4000),
        @ErrorNumber     INT,
        @ErrorSeverity   INT,
        @ErrorState      INT,
        @ErrorLine       INT,
        @ErrorProcedure  NVARCHAR(200);

    -- Assign variables to error-handling functions that 
    -- capture information for RAISERROR.
    SELECT 
        @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
        @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE(),
        @ErrorProcedure = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-');

    -- Build the message string that will contain original
    -- error information.
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = 
        N'Error %d, Level %d, State %d, Procedure %s, Line %d, ' + 
            'Message: '+ ERROR_MESSAGE();

    -- Raise an error: msg_str parameter of RAISERROR will contain
    -- the original error information.
    RAISERROR 
        (
        @ErrorMessage, 
        @ErrorSeverity, 
        1,               
        @ErrorNumber,    -- parameter: original error number.
        @ErrorSeverity,  -- parameter: original error severity.
        @ErrorState,     -- parameter: original error state.
        @ErrorProcedure, -- parameter: original error procedure name.
        @ErrorLine       -- parameter: original error line number.
        );
GO
```

Comment: that is what ERROR_PROCEDURE() does

Comment: Yes, but I would like the whole query including parameters used ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the DMVs still make it difficult to get at this information because they store the sql_text for the procedure rather than what the user actually did.  However DBCC is still your friend in a scenario like this.  Not the most efficient thing in the world but it will figure out what the user entered (not the statement in the procedure) but this could shed light on what parameters are being used when the error happens?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_RethrowError 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Return if there is no error information to retrieve.
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() IS NULL
        RETURN;

    DECLARE 
        @ErrorMessage    NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ErrorNumber     INT,
        @ErrorSeverity   INT,
        @ErrorState      INT,
        @ErrorLine       INT,
        @ErrorProcedure  NVARCHAR(200);

    -- Assign variables to error-handling functions that 
    -- capture information for RAISERROR.
    SELECT 
        @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
        @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE(),
        @ErrorProcedure = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-');

    -- Build the message string that will contain original
    -- error information.
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = 
        N'Error %d, Level %d, State %d, Procedure %s, Line %d, ' + 
            'Message: '+ ERROR_MESSAGE();

    DECLARE 
        @sql NVARCHAR(255),
        @original_statement NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = N'DBCC INPUTBUFFER(' + RTRIM(@@SPID) + ');';

    CREATE TABLE #dbcc
    (
        EventType SYSNAME,
        Parameters INT,
        EventInfo NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );

    INSERT #DBCC EXEC(@sql);

    SELECT TOP 1 @original_statement = EventInfo
        FROM #dbcc;

    SET @ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage + N'
        Original statement:
        ' + @original_statement + '
        ';

    -- Raise an error: msg_str parameter of RAISERROR will contain
    -- the original error information.
    RAISERROR 
        (
        @ErrorMessage, 
        @ErrorSeverity, 
        1,               
        @ErrorNumber,    -- parameter: original error number.
        @ErrorSeverity,  -- parameter: original error severity.
        @ErrorState,     -- parameter: original error state.
        @ErrorProcedure, -- parameter: original error procedure name.
        @ErrorLine       -- parameter: original error line number.
        );
END
GO
```

Comment: Excellent answer !

One question : Why `SELECT TOP 1 @original_statement = EventInfo FROM #dbcc;` ? Why `TOP 1` ? Does this `#dbcc` table have more than 1 row ? Or it's just to guarantee that `SELECT TOP 1 @original_statement = EventInfo` will not complain when setting the `@original_statement` variable ?

Comment: Yes I have not seen cases where this DBCC returns more than one row, but you never know when the behavior could change.  When I coded the solution I thought better safe than sorry, without having to go see if there are any exceptions to the rule.  I usually do this when assigning table results to variables in any case, though I probably should have used an ORDER BY if my excuse is to prevent undefined behavior.  :-)